# Replace function

Tags: mysql

I know what REPLACE is used for (replaces an existing string with another string wherever exists) but I'm not sure what it's doin here:

```
create temporary table tableName (
    id int primary key, 
    shared int default 0
) replace 
    select 1, userid as id 
    from cust_sharedcalendar 
    where sharedid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is mysql syntax (*not* postgres as your question tag implies).

It means the table is created and populated from the query results.

Comment: you're right about the tag but Im trying to understand what's doing here so I convert the query to postgresql

Comment: there is no equivalent syntax in postgres. try creating a view instead